# dotnet core application deployed on local service fabric throws Microsoft speech services exception

Tags: .net-core, azure-service-fabric, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I have a dotnet core 2.2 application that consumes Microsoft cognitive speech services version 1.8.0. The application is deployed on a single node local service fabric cluster.

I have added the service fabric support using visual studio 2019
*Right click on root project -> Add -> Container Orchestrator Support -> Service Fabric*

After successful deployment, when I hit the controller API I get following exception

```
> **System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
> 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll' or one of its
> dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from
> HRESULT: 0x8007007E)**    at
> Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Dialog.Internal.DialogServiceConfig.bot_framework_config_from_subscription(IntPtr&
> config, String subscription, String region)    at
> Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Dialog.BotFrameworkConfig.FromSubscription(String
> subscription, String region)    at
> WebApi.Controllers.MyController..ctor() in MyController.cs:line 71   
> at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
> Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()   
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
```

I can see the docker publish folder in dotnet core application. Publish folder has *win-x86 & win-x64 runtimes* containing native
*Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll & Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.extension.kws.dll*.

Comment: Can you check this similar [github issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/176) for some fixes people used?

Comment: @LoekD - I tried all the given options. Still no luck. Even manually adding dll to the project root didn't work either.

Comment: @LoekD - I was able to find a workaround for this issue & is posted as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround this issue as described [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/107#issuecomment-439335547).

Looks like the issue is with VC++ runtime. These dlls are required for working with Microsoft Speech APIs but are not copied into the container by default. So, I updated my docker file to copy the VC++ runtime dlls into the container & it worked.